# Can you carry peacock eggs from the USA to India in a flight?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, hand-luggage

Can you carry peacock eggs from the USA to India in carry-on luggage in an Emirates flight? And if so what is the procedure?

Comment: Do you mean eggs from which you want/have to be able to raise peacocks? Or to be used as food? I am not sure either is allowed but it might make a difference.

Comment: Or are the eggs going to be hard boiled before the flight?

Comment: I thought Peacock eggs were defenetely going to be very difficult to carry - How about some eggs of ayam cemani chicken - they are some amazing chicken species and am not sure if I would be able to get hold of them in India - so wanted to take eggs from USA to India in an Emirates Flight for raising/hatching them.@Willeke

Comment: I think you would need to check with the United States Department of Agriculture (to ensure it is legal to remove from the country), and the equivalent agency in India, and with the airline.

Answer (score 1):

Bird eggs are classified as "Restricted". [Source](http://dgft.gov.in/exim/2000/download-ftp1213.htm) -> Restricted Items. With valid explanation for the purpose you are carrying, you can take it to India.

https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/IN-India-customs-currency-airport-tax-regulations-details.htm

Comment: WARNING This is a doc file. Download at your own risk. @Santoch, don't you have a better source?

Comment: @JanDoggen : Sorry that is a link from the customs site as on google.

Comment: Thanks Santosh... that heps... Any idea how to import these exotic bird eggs... @Santosh Achari

Comment: Do check with Emirates. They should be able to guide you.